# How to pass placeholder in flyway for Insert statements?

Tags: java, flyway

I am trying to pass a placeholder value while executing Flyway.

Before calling `flyway.migrate` , I am adding the placeholder as given below:

```
String location="C:\resource";
flyway.getPlaceholders().put("resource_location",
            location);
```

The script contains the insert statement like:

```
INSERT [dbo].[resource] ([settings_id], 
[prop_key], [prop_value]) 
VALUES (1, N'resource.path', $(resource_location)/test);
```

But this does not work. Please let me know how to pass the value of placeholder to the above insert script.

Comment: I believe you should use `C:\\resource` instead of `C:\resource`

Comment: yes...I have just specified resource path as a constant. Instead  this will be taken from the server start up. But the issue is with the way I am passing the placeholder. I am getting the following exception:Caused by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/javadoc/com/googlecode/flyway/core/Flyway.html#setPlaceholderPrefix%28java.lang.String%29), the default pre- and suffixes are ${ and }.

You can either change your placeholder to ${resource_location} or reconfigure the defaults.